org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME
I have been having problem loading my spring boot project it gives me the error
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION
WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?
]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:246) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1548) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1014) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1024) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.lambda$cleanUpExpiredSessions$8(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:649) ~[spring-session-jdbc-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:648) ~[spring-session-jdbc-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "spring_session" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:371) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:502) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:419) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:975) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2024-08-06T13:32:00.008Z ERROR 11930 --- [projectname] [pring-session-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION
WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?
]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:246) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1548) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1014) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1024) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.lambda$cleanUpExpiredSessions$8(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:649) ~[spring-session-jdbc-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:648) ~[spring-session-jdbc-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "spring_session" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:371) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:502) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:419) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:975) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2024-08-06T13:33:00.005Z ERROR 11930 --- [projectname] [pring-session-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task


All the questions in S.O did not help resolve it e.g.
Spring session bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?];
Java Spring JDBC SPRING_SESSION table doesn't exist
unknown PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
etc did not help
this is my application.properties
spring.application.name=projectname
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
  
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.enabled=true


spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.port=8000


spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=900
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
# Name of the database table used to store sessions.
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION

and this is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectname</name>
    <description>Project Name</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
        <!-- SLF4J API --> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <!-- Ensure this version matches your application needs -->
                <version>2.0.13</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
     
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
                <version>1.18.34</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
          <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
          <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        
        </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>4.0.0</version>-->
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.companyname.projectname.CompanyApplication</mainClass>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I am using postgresql, i can enter into my postgre from the command line. but this is giving me error
Please what am i not doing rightly, I have spent the whole day trying to locate the reason for the error.
Thanks
Update
This is a reply to @GauthamChurchill I am not able to submit any comment. I do not know if it is my browser or what exactly is wrong
i did not create spring_session, it is automatically created by springboot itself. From my research it is used for maintaining spring session
I was given some errors when I inserted

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG

I Cannot explain what could be wrong I wanted to create a user table and set the name of the table as user, but springboot could not create it but when I changed it to users with an s attached to the end of the user it created it. but still giving error about the spring_session

Post your entity java class

The error says there is no table named spring_session org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "spring_session" does not exist. Is the name of the table correct?
